# Cocos2d iPhone: CCWave action with sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to apply ccWave action to my code. But this action is applied to whole screen. I just want to apply this action to sprite only. 
Here is my code

```
id waves = [CCWaves actionWithWaves:5 amplitude:50 horizontal:YES vertical:NO grid:ccg(15,10) duration:5];

[sprite runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: waves]];
```

Answer (score 1):

CCWave is an action that can only be applied to the whole screen. This is a cocos2d limitation. By this I mean you can apply it to a sprite but the sprite turn the everything behind the sprite black.

Update: I did a little more research and if you change the `pixelFormat` in the AppDelegate.m to `pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8` it will only apply it to the sprite.

Comment: That's pretty strange that Cocos2d does that. +1

Comment: @stenger96 thank you . so how can we give wave action only to sprite ? is there any way ??

Comment: Shaqir - Look at stenger96's update. This is old, but it may help someone else.